# Concurrency Issue in TypeORM - multiple records created when only one should be

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I've got the following code:

```
for (const vehicleDefinition of vehicleDefinitions) {
  if (vehicleDefinition) {
    const existingDefinition = await getExistingDefinition(
      vehicleService,
      vehicleDefinition.make,
      vehicleDefinition.model,
      vehicleDefinition.year
    );

    if (!existingDefinition) {
      await createNewDefinitions(
        entityManager,
        vehicleService,
       vehicleDefinition
      );
    }
  }
}

const getExistingDefinition = async (vehicleService, make, model, year) => {
  return vehicleService.retrieveDefinitionByCriteria(make, model, year);
};

const createNewDefinitions = async (
  entityManager,
  vehicleService,
  newVehicleDefinitions
) => {
  if (newVehicleDefinitions.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  await entityManager.transaction(async (manager) => {
    const promises = newVehicleDefinitions.map(async (newVehicleDefinition) => {
      await vehicleService
        .withTransaction(manager)
        .createDefinition(newVehicleDefinition);
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
  });
};
```

However for some reason, sometimes new transactions are happening, before old ones complete. This is using TypeORM.

I am trying to wrap everything in async/await, but with no luck, it STILL manages to start a new transaction before an old one is finished. Essentially multiple instances of createNewDefinitions are being called, before the transaction in one of them is complete.

What am I doing wrong to prevent concurrency issues?

Comment: What database? Transactions can generally run concurrently, even on the same data. If you want only one instance of `createNewDefinitions` to run you'll need locks, not transactions. Locking can be achieved with isolation levels when opening a transaction (in some databases), explicit database locks (table write locks, for example), file locks, system mutexes, etc.